# Plug-Start-Pull Windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch, usb-flash-drive

I'd like to preface this by saying I'm not a system administrator at all, just a lowly Java programmer. However, I've been tasked with writing a batch script to be run on a sizable number of laptop computers. The script is done, but there's a catch (of course).

They want to be able to plug in a thumb drive containing the script, start it, and pull the thumb drive for the next computer but leave the script running. Oh, and for some reason, using the laptops' built-in wireless to pull the script from a shared network folder isn't an option.

I want to know if there's a good (and preferably easy) way to do this. I thought about having a script on the thumb drive copy the needed script to the hard drive then start it, but I don't know if it will work and I don't really want to leave it on the hard drive after it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really more of a question for stack overflow I think, because these are all problems that can be solved programatically.

What I would do is:

1. On the USB stick, create an autorun.inf that executes the bootstrapper script
2. The bootstrapper script copies a 2nd script (the one you want to run) to the %TEMP% folder
3. Starts a new process that executes the 2nd script
4. Bootstrapper script stops executing
5. Pull the USB stick out

As to how to achieve this? [SO awaits](http://www.stackoverflow.com/)! And the use of the %TEMP% folder is because it will be cleared out by the system eventually I believe.

P.S. Is your avatar the explosion from the intro movie to the original C&C game, circa 1995?

Comment: Remember that Autorun from USB doesn't work anymore as of Windows 7.

Comment: Just a note that, at least prior to Vista, Windows will not clean out the %TEMP% folder. It may cleanout some of what it puts in there itself (on a really good day) but will not clean up after other apps.

Comment: These are rental lappies from Dell so if they don't have 7 now they probably will later. I won't bother with the autorun; thanks for the idea with %TEMP% though. I'll ask on SO. 

Oh, and it's just a random mushroom cloud pic I found. It could be from C&C (great game) for all I know.

Comment: @Johannes, I didn't know this, thanks for the tip. @John, I belive the Disk Cleanup wizard will empty it out, but good point.